# How to convert XML into XPS format for printing

Tags: c#, xml, xps

How can I can convert xml into a printable xps document?

Comment: Umm.. XPS *IS* XML.  Do you mean you want to print the contents of an XML file to an XPS document?

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163664.aspx#S5 has a good example of doing what you want.

You still have to decide how the xml should be stored in XPS document

Comment: for the umpteenth time... a dead Microsoft link

Answer (score 0):

This site gave me an option to improve my answer, instead I'll improve the question.

I have a bare raw `XML` output and would like to package the `XML` code and format it in an `XPS` doc.
The link Mr Rajkumar is long dead and any recollection of the `MSDN` issue, article name.

What I'd like to do is to select one or more `XPS Print Ticket` templates and add some formatting in order to encase bare forms (input text fields) and make them more presentable.